# Unable to find Encode[Char] while using flatMap with toCharArray in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, flatmap

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
var names = Seq("ABC","XYZ").toDF("names")
var data = names.flatMap(name=>name.getString(0).toCharArray).map(rec=> 
                              (rec,1)).rdd.reduce((x,y)=>('S',x._2 + y._2))
```

ERROR: Error:(20, 27) Unable to find encoder for type Char. An implicit Encoder[Char] is needed to store Char instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
var data = names.flatMap(name=>name.getString(0).toCharArray).map(rec=>(rec,1)).rdd.reduce((x,y)=>('S',x._2 + y._2))

Comment: What is your expected output? What are you trying to do with the code?

Comment: I am trying to get SUM of all characters, I am able to do it by following code: names.flatMap(name=>name.getString(0).split("")).map(rec=>(rec,1)).rdd.reduce((x,y)=>("SUM",x._2 + y._2)), but instead of using split(""), if I try to use toCharArray it was failing, so tring understand this need of Encoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the dataframe to RDD first before doing the `flatMap` and `map` operations:

```
var data = names.rdd
                .flatMap(name => name.getString(0).toCharArray)
                .map(rec => (rec, 1))
                .reduce((x, y) => ('S', x._2 + y._2))
```

which will return 6, because you're just counting the number of chars in the first column of the dataframe. Not sure if this is your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but why its failing for dataframe, why its needed to convert in dataframe. I am able to get whats needed by: I am trying to get SUM of all characters, I am able to do it by following code: names.flatMap(name=>name.getString(0).split("")).map(rec=>(rec,1)).rdd.reduce((x,y)=>("SUM",x._2 + y._2)), but instead of using split(""), if I try to use toCharArray it was failing, so tring understand this need of Encoder

Comment: In a dataset the values have to be serialized/encoded. If you use split, it will give strings, which belongs to a default Spark data type and can be encoded, but if you use `toCharArray`, char is not a default Spark datatype and so it cannot be encoded.