# Why does RDD work when I don't have the implicit encoder? Why does providing an implicit encoder also fix the issue?

Tags: apache-spark

The Spark quickstart example provides some code to count the occurrences of each word that appears in the README.md document:

```
val textFile = spark.read.textFile("README.md")
textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).groupByKey(identity).count().collect()
res0: Array[(String, Long)] = Array(([![PySpark,1), (online,1), (graphs,1), (["Building,1), (documentation,3), (command,,2), (abbreviated,1), (overview,1), (rich,1), (set,2), (-DskipTests,1), (1,000,000,000:,2), (name,1), (["Specifying,1), (stream,1), (run:,1), (not,1), (programs,2), (tests,2), (./dev/run-tests,1), (will,1), ([run,1), (particular,2), (Alternatively,,1), (must,1), (using,3), (./build/mvn,1), (you,4), (MLlib,1), (DataFrames,,1), (variable,1), (Note,1), (core,1), (protocols,1), (Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html),1), (guidance,2), (shell:,2), (can,6), (site,,1), (*,4), (systems.,1), ([building,1), (configure,1), (for,12), (README,1), (Interactive,2), (how,3), ([Configuration,1), (Hive,2), (provides,1), (Hadoop-supporte...
```

I thought it would be a good excercise to figure out how to modify the code so that I could count the characters instead of the words. I inncorrectly assume I could replace `line.split(" ")` which toCharArray(). The original was a list of String, the replacement is a list of Char. This didn't work:

```
textFile.flatMap(line => line.toCharArray()).groupByKey(identity).count().collect()
<console>:24: error: Unable to find encoder for type Char. An implicit Encoder[Char] is needed to store Char instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
       textFile.flatMap(line => line.toCharArray()).groupByKey(identity).count().collect()
                       ^
<console>:24: error: missing argument list for method identity in object Predef
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `identity _` or `identity(_)` instead of `identity`.
       textFile.flatMap(line => line.toCharArray()).groupByKey(identity).count().collect()
```

After exploring stack overflow for the error message I found [Unable to find Encode[Char] while using flatMap with toCharArray in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646674/unable-to-find-encodechar-while-using-flatmap-with-tochararray-in-spark?rq=1) which says you need to use rdd. As a result, I modified the above with rdd:

```
textFile.flatMap(line => line.split("")).groupByKey(identity).count().collect()
res6: Array[(String, Long)] = Array((K,1), (7,3), (l,156), (x,12), (=,5), (<,2), (],19), (g,96), (3,3), (F,7), (Q,2), (*,4), (0,37), (m,75), (!,4), (E,9), (T,14), (f,47), (B,6), ((,22), (n,225), (k,58), (.,81), (_,4), (Y,6), (L,4), (M,8), (V,3), (U,2), (v,43), (e,316), (D,8), (O,2), (o,246), (h,126), (z,1), (C,5), (p,160), (d,108), (J,2), (-,35), (A,18), (/,109), (N,5), (X,1), (y,38), (w,23), (),22), (c,116), (S,35), (u,119), (:,29), (i,215), (R,9), (G,3), (",12), (1,8), (q,2), (j,8), (#,22), (%,1), (`,6), (b,59), (I,6), (&,1), (P,14), (,,32), (a,299), (r,230), ("",41), (" ",462), (?,3), (t,264), (>,6), (2,2), (H,10), (s,228), ([,19))
```

The issue is summarized by a commenter in the linked stack overflow article:

> char is not a default Spark datatype and so it cannot be encoded.

An alternative solution is also using rdd as suggested in one of the answers from the article:

```
textFile.rdd.flatMap(line => line.toCharArray().map(c=>(c,1))).reduceByKey(_+_).collect()
res7: Array[(Char, Int)] = Array((w,23), (",12), (`,6), (Q,2), (e,316), (G,3), (7,3), (R,9), (B,6), (P,14), (O,2), (b,59), (y,38), (A,18), (#,22), (2,2), (h,126), (o,246), (i,215), (K,1), (3,3), (%,1), (k,58), (n,225), (-,35), (j,8), (J,2), (?,3), (H,10), (S,35), (F,7), (Y,6), (&,1), (1,8), (g,96), (N,5), (l,156), (m,75), (c,116), (T,14), (d,108), (),22), (=,5), (z,1), (s,228), (/,109), (L,4), (x,12), (p,160), (M,8), (a,299), (_,4), (t,264), (.,81), (0,37), (u,119), (I,6), ( ,462), (>,6), (],19), (!,4), (*,4), (f,47), (q,2), (v,43), ((,22), (C,5), (E,9), (U,2), (:,29), (,,32), (V,3), (<,2), ([,19), (X,1), (r,230), (D,8))
```

Given my experience above I have a fundamental misunderstanding. I have these two questions to help me understand spark better:

1. Why does RDD work with a non-primitive type?
2. Why does providing an implicit encoder also fix the issue? How can I provide an implicit Encoder[Char], so that I don't need RDD?